# How to create Push Notification for new-post in wordpress for android studio?

Tags: wordpress, android-studio

I am creating a wordpress android application. Have one doubt.
I need to integrate OneSignal for my application.
I need to send automated PushNotification to the users, when new post added. 
(I am following this tutorial "https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs". But I need to send automated PushNotification to the users, when new post added.)

Please advice how can i implement

Comment: Hey, did you find a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please try [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/push-notifications-for-wp/) plugin for your purpose.